# how to recover back the pictures from my nexus 5x after factory reset?

Tags: google-play-store, data-recovery, restore, hard-reset

i am facing some issue  with google playstore( it cannot download or update any application) so i did all possible methods to make it function normally and at last with no other way left out i tried hard reset even then the problem is not resolved and all data is erased..
Dear experts kindly help me to recover the pictures and also to fix the play store issue..

Device model : LG-Google Nexus 5x 
Andriod Verision : N

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially impossible to recover data from a phone once it's been factory reset, especially since the Nexus 5X is [encrypted by default](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2844831?hl=en-GB). If you had Auto Backup enabled, you may be able to find them on [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com), but otherwise they're probably gone for good.

If you want help on another topic (e.g. fixing the Play Store), I suggest [asking a new question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and including as many details as you can about what exactly doesn't work.